# Is it possible to edit cells in a sheet which is (Visible) but not currently activated?

Tags: excel, vba

Hello I was wondering if there was a way to edit cells within a sheet without it being "Activated" (Sheet is visible not hidden).

```vb
NHBR:
    With Worksheets("Summary")
    'Book to Floor Summary
        Range("C1").Value = "Compliance Progress Summary"
        Range("C3").Value = "Book To Floor"
        Range("C5").Value = "Room"
        Range("D5").Value = "Expected Number Of Assets"
        Range("E5").Value = "Number Of Assets Found"
        Range("F5").Value = "% of Assets Found"
        Range("G5").Value = "Number Of Assets Not Found"
        Range("C6").Value = "NORTH"
        Range("C7").Value = "EAST"
        Range("C8").Value = "SOUTH"
        Range("C9").Value = "WEST"
        Range("C11").Value = "STORE"
        Range("C13").Value = "Total Assets"
    end with
```

is there a way to just use

```vb
with Worksheets("Summary")
```

or does it have to be

```vb
Worksheets("Summary").Actiavte
```

Comment: Add a period `.` in front of each `Range` instance.

Comment: You can edit cells in *any* sheet, assuming it's not protected - it does not have to be active, or even visible: hidden sheets are also accessible to your (fixed) code.

Comment: If you write `Range` (without `.`), you are referring to the *ActiveSheet*. To access a property of the object you are using in the `With`-Clause, use `.Range`(with a `.`)

Comment: @BigBen Thank you, the simple answers always seem to be the hardest to find, thank you very much!

Comment: @FunThomas Thanks, it makes sense once it has been explained

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my opinion the best approach is:

```
With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Summary")
'Book to Floor Summary
    .Range("C1").Value = "Compliance Progress Summary"
    .Range("C3").Value = "Book To Floor"
    .Range("C5").Value = "Room"
    .Range("D5").Value = "Expected Number Of Assets"
    .Range("E5").Value = "Number Of Assets Found"
    .Range("F5").Value = "% of Assets Found"
    .Range("G5").Value = "Number Of Assets Not Found"
    .Range("C6").Value = "NORTH"
    .Range("C7").Value = "EAST"
    .Range("C8").Value = "SOUTH"
    .Range("C9").Value = "WEST"
    .Range("C11").Value = "STORE"
    .Range("C13").Value = "Total Assets"
End With
```

---

```
Sub test()

    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Summary")

        With .Range("A1")
            .Value = "Compliance Progress Summary"
            .Font.Size = 10
            .Interior.Color = RGB(255, 255, 143)
        End With
    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: In my opinion is better to refer both workbook & worksheet

Comment: Sounds like a good idea to refer to both.

```vba
With ThisWorkBook.WorkSheets("Summary")
     .Range("A1").value = "Compliance Progress Summary"
          .Font.Size = 10
          .Interior.color = RGB (255, 255, 143)
```

Could something like this work as I tried it but it doesn't work.
Am I going to have to reference the same cell every time I want to make a change to it?

Comment: @Brendan-JohnMartin see edited answer to get your answer

Comment: you creare a `With Statement` with the sheet name and another `With Statement` with the range you want to change.

Comment: Do not that [`ThisWorkBook`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/Excel.Application.ThisWorkbook) refers to the workbook containing the macro, which may or may not be the workbook you are working on.

Comment: 'Thisworkbook' refer to the workbook where the code is. The ultimate solution if you have many workbooks you should declare variables for each workbook